# Grab value from specific column in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, command-line

I have problem with grabbing values from specific column in text file using awk command.
This is the text file `sample.txt` :

```
      Apps                  Command            Status            From           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc-admin          vwxyz -g daemon off;        Up      1.2.3.4:82->80/tcp       
abc-app            vwxyz -g daemon off;        Exit 0  1.2.3.4:83->80/tcp       
abc-docs           aaaaaa-xxxxxxxxxx.sh        Up      1.2.3.4:3001->3000/tcp   
                   /bin/ ...                                                    
abc-mail           aaaaaa-xxxxxxxxxx.sh asd    Exit 1  1.2.3.4:3011->3000/tcp   
                   r ...                                                        
abc-encr           java -cp app:app/lib/*      Up      1.2.3.4:3011->8080/tcp   
                   enc ...                                                      
abc_admin          aaaaaa-xxxxxxxxxx.sh node   Up      1.2.3.4:3012->3000/tcp   
                   .                                                            
abc_bat            /bin/sh -c ./jkl-           Exit 2  1.2.3.4:3013->3000/tcp   
                   yyyyyyyy. ...                                                
abc_conn           /bin/sh -c ./jkl-           Up      3000/tcp                 
                   yyyyyyyy. ...                                                
abc_cust           /bin/sh -c ./jkl-           Up      1.2.3.4:3001->3000/tcp   
                   yyyyyyyy. ...                                                
abc_exp            ads start                   Up      1.2.3.4:3008->3000/tcp   
abc_gw             node .                      Up      1.2.3.4:8080->3200/tcp,  
                                                       80/tcp                   
abc_logs           /usr/local/bin/aaaaaa-      Up      1.2.3.4:5000->5000/tcp,  
                   entr ...                            5044/tcp,                
                                                       1.2.3.4:9600->9600/tcp
```

I've tried with `awk '/abc/ {print $1,$3}' sample.txt` but it gives this output:

```
abc-admin -g
abc-app -g
abc-docs Up
abc-mail npm
abc-encr -cp
abc_admin node
abc_bat -c
abc_conn -c
abc_cust -c
abc_exp start
abc_gw .
abc_logs Up
```

I just realized that the separator between column is not a tab (\t).
Is there other way to grab values from 1st and 3rd column?
Expected result is:

```
abc-admin Up
abc-app Exit 0
abc-docs Up
abc-mail Exit 1
abc-encr Up
abc_admin Up
abc_bat Exit 2
abc_conn Up
abc_cust Up
abc_exp Up
abc_gw Up
abc_logs Up
```

Comment: The 3rd column in your first line **is**  -g. Just have a look at the white space! The problem is that when you treat white space as field separator, the lines have different numbers of fields. In your input data, what you call "column" means _to start at a certain position in a line_. If these positions don't change (so they can be hard-coded), you could just read the file line by line and extract the strings at these positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following, tested and written with provided samples.

```
awk '
FNR>2 && /^[^ ]/{
  if($(NF-1)~/[0-9]/){
    print $1,$(NF-2),$(NF-1)
  }
  else{
    print $1,$(NF-1)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

I have also considered that your last field is NOT having any spaces in it.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Considering that your last field can have spaces in it, in that case one could try following.

```
awk '
FNR>2 && /^[^ ]/{
  match($0,/ +[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.*/)
  val=split(substr($0,1,RSTART-1),array," ")
  if(array[val]~/[0-9]/){
    print $1,array[val-1],array[val]
  }
  else{
    print $1,array[val]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

In both of my solutions I have considered that `exit` will have a status in digits with it, which I believe is a fair consideration.

Comment: thank you, but it only works for the "Up" state only, while the "Exit" state is only the number (0 / 1 / 2)

Comment: @ZulfikarSandyPratama, Is it always going to be only either `Up` or `exit` states? Or any more will be there?

Comment: @ZulfikarSandyPratama, Please try edited solution once?

Comment: Im not sure because I can only read the `sample.txt` file after it is generated by something else (not under me). Btw both solutions work fine. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed width fields. Using GNU awk to specify the field widths with FIELDWIDTHS and then gensub() to remove extraneous blanks between them:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="19 28 8 *" 'NR<3{next} $1~/[^ ]/{print gensub(/ +/," ","g",$1" "$3)}' file
abc-admin Up
abc-app Exit 0
abc-docs Up
abc-mail Exit 1
abc-encr Up
abc_admin Up
abc_bat Exit 2
abc_conn Up
abc_cust Up
abc_exp Up
abc_gw Up
abc_logs Up
```